# É possível passar campos como parâmetro para uma Trigger Function em PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Tendo como exemplo uma tabela de usuário:

```sql
create table pessoa {
   id serial pk,
   nome varchar(255),
   telefone varchar(20),
   cpf varchar(20)
}
```

Nesta minha tabela gostaria de armazenar apenas os números nos campos `telefone` e `cpf`:
`(01) 23456-7890 -> 01234567890` e a mesma coisa para o `cpf`. Porém eu queria saber se seria possível, na minha `trigger`, passar os parâmetros para a `function`.

Minha ideia de como ficaria a `function`:

```sql
create or replace function format_trigger_function()
returns trigger as $$
declare
   arg var;
begin
   foreach arg in array TG_ARGV loop
      arg = regexp_replace(arg, '\D', '', 'g');

      ou

      new.arg = regexp_replace(arg, '\D', '', 'g');
   end loop;
   return new;
end $$ language plpgsql;
```

**Nota:** Eu não sei exatamente qual seria o tipo de dado no `declare`, então coloquei `var`.

E minha `trigger` ficaria:

```sql
create trigger format_trigger_pessoa
before insert or update on pessoa
for each row
execute procedure format_trigger_function(telefone, cpf);
```

Dessa forma, se futuramente eu adicionar novos campos que necessitem dessa formatação eu precisaria apenas alterar a `trigger`. O mesmo vale caso eu queira criar outras tabelas que utilizem esta `function`.

**Nota:** Só para esclarecer, minha dúvida é tanto uma forma de passar um campo para a `function` quanto resolver o problema da formatação dos campos. Esta foi a forma que encontrei, mas não significa que seja a melhor forma. Então se houver alguma forma melhor de corrigir o problema da formatação, também gostaria de ver.

Answer (score -1):

Uma forma de resolver isso é:

1. converter o `NEW` para json, para acessar dinamicamente o valor da coluna.
2. usar o [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html) junto com o operador [#=](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE) para fazer o replace dinâmico do valor. É necessário habilitar a extensão antes: `CREATE EXTENSION hstore;`

O código abaixo é um exemplo de resolução.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION format_trigger_function()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    arg varchar;
    raw_value varchar;
    formated_value varchar;
    row json;
BEGIN
    row = to_json(NEW.*);
    FOREACH arg IN ARRAY TG_ARGV LOOP
        raw_value = row->arg;
        formated_value = regexp_replace(raw_value, '\D', '', 'g');
        NEW := NEW #= hstore(arg, formated_value);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NEW;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER format_trigger_pessoa BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON pessoa
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE format_trigger_function(cpf, telefone);
```

A variável [NEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#:%7E:text=NEW,for%20DELETE%20operations.) é um tipo record, ou seja, um [Composite Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/rowtypes.html), então somente é possível acessar uma coluna informando o atributo (NEW.telefone, NEW.cpf). O SQL mesmo não permite identificadores dinâmicos.

Comment: Olá @Rafael obrigado pela resposta. Tentei executar seu código e o pgAdmin me retornou o seguinte erro:

ERROR:  function hstore(character varying, character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT NEW #= hstore(arg, formated_value)
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT NEW #= hstore(arg, formated_value)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function patrimoniodb.format_trigger_function() line 12 at assignment
SQL state: 42883

Acredito que precise fazer algumas mudanças na classe para que funcione.

Comment: Só para esclarecer que não foi eu quem deu down vote, mas eu olhei pouca coisa sobre o `hstore`, já que não tenho muita familiarização com `sql` e não sabia como funcionava, e pelo que entendi eu teria que fazer alguns ajustes na minha classe para que funcione corretamente, me corrija se eu estiver errado. A principio não pretendo fazer mudanças na classe, a menos que seja necessário. Então se for a única solução encontrada irei fazer como você sugeriu e irei marcar sua resposta como solução.

Comment: Me desculpe @LuizFelipeRodrigues, faltou informar que o `hstore` é uma extensão que precisa ser habilitada no Database. Você pode instalar o módulo com um `CREATE EXTENSION hstore;`. Vou complementar a resposta com esse passo.